# creating an iterator in Python from a dictionary in memory-efficient way

Tags: python, scripting, loops, memory-efficient

I'm iterating through a very large tab-delimited file (containing millions of lines) and pairing different lines of it based on the value of some field in that file, e.g.

```
mydict = defaultdict()
for line in myfile:
  # Group all lines that have the same field into a list
  mydict[line.field].append(line)
```

Since "mydict" gets very large, I'd like to make it into an iterator so I don't have to hold it all in memory.  How can I make it so instead of populating a dictionary, I will create an iterator that I can loop through and get all these lists of lines that have the same field value?

Thanks.

Comment: you must show how mydict is being used, otherwise it's impossible to tell

Comment: How many millions of lines? Average line length? What is the nature of `field`? You say "pairing" ... "pair" implies 2; what are expected min, max and average size of resulting lists? What do you plan to do with the results ... find duplicate records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"millions of lines" is not very large unless the lines are long. If the lines are long you might save some memory by storing only positions in the file (`.tell()`/`.seek()`).

If the file is sorted by `line.field`; you could use [itertools.groupby()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

SQL’s `GROUP BY` might help for average-sized files (e.g., using `sqlite` as [@wisty suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451159/creating-an-iterator-in-python-from-a-dictionary-in-memory-efficient-way/5451226#5451226)).

For really large files you could use [MapReduce](http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2010/01/mapreduce-for-idiots.html).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might want a database. There's a variety of relational and non-relational databases you can pick from (some more efficient than others, depending on what you are trying to achieve), but sqlite (built into python) would be the easiest.

Or, if there are only a small number of line.fields to process, you could just read the files several times.

But there's no real magic bullet.